# Convert Integer to Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a view that is connected to two tables from two different databases

I'm trying to:

1. convert the two columns below from `int` to `decimal` with 4 precision

   ```
    [Talk_Count] + [Alloc_Count] AS [Talk] 
    [CT_Count] - [NP_Count] / [CT_Count] AS [Quality]
   ```
2. Sort the data

   ```
     WHERE [Call_Date]  <= 13
   ```

How do I do it, below is what my view structure looks like

```
SELECT
    Call_DT, 
    Talk_Sec_Count + Alloc_Sec_Count AS Talk,
    CT_Count - NP_Count  /    CT_Count AS Quality,
    Pymt_Rtn_Rt AS Utilization,
    Agent_UID
FROM 
    [TableName]
```

Comment: What does "sort" mean in reference to `WHERE` (that is a filter not a sort)

Comment: What did your research show you when you googled "sql convert int to decimal"? Its not a new problem. And what did your research show you with regard to sql sorting data?

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` isn't used to do sorting...... and you cannot sort inside a view definition - you can sort (by using an explicit `ORDER BY`) when you `SELECT` from that view.

You could try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourViewNameHere
AS 
     SELECT
         Call_DT, 
         CAST(Talk_Sec_Count + Alloc_Sec_Count AS DECIMAL(16, 4)) AS Talk,
         CAST(CT_Count * 1.0 - NP_Count  / CT_Count * 1.0 AS DECIMAL(16, 4)) AS Quality,
         Pymt_Rtn_Rt AS Utilization,
         Agent_UID
     FROM 
         [TableName] 
     WHERE
         [Call_Date]  <= 13     -- not clear if that's really your condition.... adapt as needed
```

And then you can `SELECT` from that view and add your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT             
    Call_DT, Talk, Quality, Utilization, Agent_UID
FROM
    dbo.YourViewNameHere
ORDER BY
    Call_DT  -- or order by whatever column you need
```

Comment: Thank you so much marc_s, you are indeed a true MVP.

Comment: @SQLGrab: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.